# comparar string

Tags: python

Tenho um input com o nome de "cidade" que é uma string e preciso fazer com que se o usuário digitar um numero ou não digitar nada ele receba uma mensagem de erro, como eu poderia fazer?

Segue o código

```
import requests
import json
from googletrans import Translator


class Temperatura():
    while True:
        cidade = input("Escreva sua cidade para consultar o tempo: ")
        requisicao = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cidade +
                                  "&appid=KEY")
        tempo = json.loads(requisicao.text)
        des = tempo['weather'][0]['description']
        hu = tempo['main']['humidity']
        t = tempo['main']['temp'] -273.15
        #tradução
        translator = Translator()
        des_t = translator.translate(des, dest='pt').text
        print('Condição do tempo:', des_t,',temperatura de', round(t),'graus','e umidade a',hu,'%')
```

Comment: Essa classe `Temperatura` tem um `while` assim mesmo? Sem métodos?

Comment: sim, porém mais embaixo eu tenho outro input, que dependendo da resposta ele para a classe e inicia outra.

Comment: Parece que você utilizou classe de forma equivocada aí. Isso poderia ser uma função apenas.

Comment: Já corrigi, obrigado pela ideia.

Comment: Tem diversos outros erros ai, mesmo que você troque `class` por `def` não será feito requisição nenhuma. recomendo uma leitura melhor na doc da api. além desses dois links para referencias de [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) e [funções](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Como o seu input é do tipo `str` mesmo que o usuário digite `12345`, por exemplo, o programa não entenderá como `int`. Assim, sugiro criar uma variável e colocar lá dentro tudo o que você deseja **não aceitar**, como números, caracteres especiais, etc.

```
class Temperatura():

excluir = r"/\?%0123456789,."
while True:
    cidade = input("Escreva sua cidade para consultar o tempo: ")
    invalido = any(elem in cidade for elem in excluir)
    if cidade != '' and invalido == False:
        requisicao = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cidade +
                                  "&appid=KEY")
        tempo = json.loads(requisicao.text)
        des = tempo['weather'][0]['description']
        hu = tempo['main']['humidity']
        t = tempo['main']['temp'] -273.15
        #tradução
        translator = Translator()
        des_t = translator.translate(des, dest='pt').text
        print('Condição do tempo:', des_t,',temperatura de', round(t),'graus','e umidade a',hu,'%')
    else:
      print('mensagem de erro')
```

Comment: Sugiro corrigir a classe que não é classe também; e preciso dizer que ficou bastante confuso exibir uma mensagem de erro quando `valido` for verdadeiro. Se é válido, por que daria erro?

Comment: Verdade haha. Corrigi para `invalido`